# Kubernetes path understanding. spec.containers[].securityContext.runAsUser and - spec.containers[*].securityContext.runAsGroup

Tags: kubernetes

What is the meaning of the [] in this kubernetes path.

spec.containers[].securityContext.runAsUser -
spec.containers[*].securityContext.runAsGroup

what is the meaning and difference between [] and [*]

What they mean []Container in below document page
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/

PodSpec
PodSpec is a description of a pod.

Containers
containers ([]Container), ......

initContainers ([]Container)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a typo. They didn't mean for this to look different.

The Pod schema includes a `spec.containers` field, which is an array. When we talk about `spec.cointainers[].<some-key>` or `spec.cointainers[*].<some-key>` , we would refer to a subkey, which could be found in any item in that containers array.

The `securityContext.runAsUser` would set the user id running processes in your container, while the `securityContext.runAsGroup` would set the group id for that container.

While you mention initContainers as well: this is pretty much the same as your containers. While schema is the same: usage is different. containers listed in `initContainers` would execute first, and are expected to exit, once done initializing your runtime. While containers from the `containers` list would only start once your pod is initialized.